# If key is number its automatically aligned to left in table created from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am creating HTML table with JSON data My HTML Table is  dynamic..But the problem is i am having number as a key for some column but if i am using number as a key the column of the table automatically gets aligned on to the left of the table.

If anyone found my mistake or syntax wrong please let me know guys. But as far as i know i have done the right coding, But don't know why the number key is automatically aligned to left most.
I want to locate that column where it is coming into the JSON format

```js
var tableValue = [{
  "OUTLET": "Ol1",
  "BILLDATE": "01-08-18",
  "TOTAL": "10",
  "AMOUNT": "2",
  "": "2",
  "5": "4"
}, {
  "OUTLET": "ol1",
  "BILLDATE": "02-08-18",
  "TOTAL": "20",
  "AMOUNT": "4",
  "": "4",
  "5": "4"
}, {
  "OUTLET": "ol1",
  "BILLDATE": "03-08-18",
  "TOTAL": "30",
  "AMOUNT": "6",
  "": "6",
  "5": "4"
}, {
  "OUTLET": "ol1",
  "BILLDATE": "04-08-18",
  "TOTAL": "40",
  "AMOUNT": "8",
  "": "8",
  "5": "4"
}, {
  "OUTLET": "ol2",
  "BILLDATE": "01-08-18",
  "TOTAL": "15",
  "AMOUNT": "3",
  "": "3",
  "5": "4"
}, {
  "OUTLET": "ol2",
  "BILLDATE": "02-08-18",
  "TOTAL": "25",
  "AMOUNT": "5",
  "": "5",
  "5": "4"
}, {
  "OUTLET": "ol2",
  "BILLDATE": "03-08-18",
  "TOTAL": "35",
  "AMOUNT": "7",
  "": "7",
  "5": "4"
}, {
  "OUTLET": "ol2",
  "BILLDATE": "04-08-18",
  "TOTAL": "45",
  "AMOUNT": "9",
  "": "9",
  "5": "4"
}, {
  "OUTLET": "ol3",
  "BILLDATE": "01-08-18",
  "TOTAL": "14",
  "AMOUNT": "2",
  "": "4",
  "5": "4"
}, {
  "OUTLET": "ol3",
  "BILLDATE": "02-08-18",
  "TOTAL": "24",
  "AMOUNT": "4",
  "": "4",
  "5": "4"
}, {
  "OUTLET": "ol3",
  "BILLDATE": "03-08-18",
  "TOTAL": "34",
  "AMOUNT": "5",
  "": "9",
  "5": "4"
}, {
  "OUTLET": "ol3",
  "BILLDATE": "04-08-18",
  "TOTAL": "44",
  "AMOUNT": "8",
  "": "12",
  "5": "4"
}]

function addTable() {
  var col = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < tableValue.length; i++) {
    for (var key in tableValue[i]) {
      if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
        col.push(key);
      }
    }
  }

  // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
  var table = document.createElement("table");

  // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
  }

  // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
  for (var i = 0; i < tableValue.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      tabCell.innerHTML = tableValue[i][col[j]];
    }
  }

  // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("newTable");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
}
addTable()
```

Here is [My js fiddle link of my table](https://jsfiddle.net/draj8126/8th5dykj/64/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties order in objects is not guaranteed in JavaScript.

You can `splice()` all the number item from the array to `concat()` with the remaining array. Also you can reduce the code to create the array of keys using `Object.keys()`.

Try the following:

```js
var tableValue = [{
        "OUTLET": "Ol1",
        "BILLDATE": "01-08-18",
        "TOTAL": "10",
        "AMOUNT": "2",
        "1": "2",
        "2": "2",
        "3": "2",
        "4": "2",
        "5": "4"
    },
    {
        "OUTLET": "ol1",
        "BILLDATE": "02-08-18",
        "TOTAL": "20",
        "AMOUNT": "4",
        "1": "4",
        "2": "2",
        "3": "2",
        "4": "2",
        "5": "4"
        
    },
    {
        "OUTLET": "ol1",
        "BILLDATE": "03-08-18",
        "TOTAL": "30",
        "AMOUNT": "6",
        "1": "6",
        "2": "2",
        "3": "2",
        "4": "2",
        "5": "4"
    },
    {
        "OUTLET": "ol1",
        "BILLDATE": "04-08-18",
        "TOTAL": "40",
        "AMOUNT": "8",
        "1": "8",
        "2": "2",
        "3": "2",
        "4": "2",
        "5": "4"
    },
    {
        "OUTLET": "ol2",
        "BILLDATE": "01-08-18",
        "TOTAL": "15",
        "AMOUNT": "3",
        "1": "3",
        "2": "2",
        "3": "2",
        "4": "2",
        "5": "4"
    },
    {
        "OUTLET": "ol2",
        "BILLDATE": "02-08-18",
        "TOTAL": "25",
        "AMOUNT": "5",
        "1": "5",
        "2": "2",
        "3": "2",
        "4": "2",
        "5": "4"
    },
    {
        "OUTLET": "ol2",
        "BILLDATE": "03-08-18",
        "TOTAL": "35",
        "AMOUNT": "7",
        "1": "7",
        "2": "2",
        "3": "2",
        "4": "2",
        "5": "4"
    },
    {
        "OUTLET": "ol2",
        "BILLDATE": "04-08-18",
        "TOTAL": "45",
        "AMOUNT": "9",
        "1": "9",
        "2": "2",
        "3": "2",
        "4": "2",
        "5": "4"
    },
    {
        "OUTLET": "ol3",
        "BILLDATE": "01-08-18",
        "TOTAL": "14",
        "AMOUNT": "2",
        "1": "4",
        "2": "2",
        "3": "2",
        "4": "2",
        "5": "4"
    },
    {
        "OUTLET": "ol3",
        "BILLDATE": "02-08-18",
        "TOTAL": "24",
        "AMOUNT": "4",
        "1": "4",
        "2": "2",
        "3": "2",
        "4": "2",
        "5": "4"
    },
    {
        "OUTLET": "ol3",
        "BILLDATE": "03-08-18",
        "TOTAL": "34",
        "AMOUNT": "5",
        "1": "9",
        "2": "2",
        "3": "2",
        "4": "2",
        "5": "4"
    },
    {
        "OUTLET": "ol3",
        "BILLDATE": "04-08-18",
        "TOTAL": "44",
        "AMOUNT": "8",
        "1": "12",
        "2": "2",
        "3": "2",
        "4": "2",
        "5": "4"
    }

]

 function addTable() {
    var col = Object.keys(tableValue[0]); // get all the keys from first object
    var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length; // count all  which are number
    var num = col.splice(0, countNum); // cut five elements from frist
    col = col.concat(num); // shift the first item to last
    // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
    var table = document.createElement("table");

    // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.


      for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < tableValue.length; i++) {

        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = tableValue[i][col[j]];
        }
    }

    // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("newTable");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
}
addTable()
```

```css
th, td, p, input {
    font:14px Verdana;
}
table, th, td 
{
    border: solid 1px #DDD;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
th {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="newTable" class="table table-striped" border="2">
</table>
```

Comment: Bro there is a problem there, If i have only one key as no then its working fine but i have more then 15 keys as a number so its just shifting the first one...  look at this fiddle link  https://jsfiddle.net/draj8126/8th5dykj/68/ i have added total 5 columns which has key as a number but its only shifting the first one. :(

Comment: @dheerajkumar, in that case cut all the number using `splice()` then `concat()`....I have updated the answer.....please check.....thanks.

Comment: OK.. so i have to use splice(0,5). but if the keys are dynamic then it can vary from sometimes 5 and some times 10.Then what can i do bro?

Comment: @Mamum  Thanks alot for your time bro

Comment: @dheerajkumar, you are most welcome...happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is just basic CSS - add `text-align: right;` to the relevant column elements. (You probably need to add a class to the `td` elements for that column, if you haven't already.)

Answer (score 0):

You  need to align column explicitly.
In table header of Key Column add style to align it center.
Also in  of same column which belongs to key column align them center.

You can do this with the help of css.

Comment: Without explaining how you do that, this would seem to be a pretty useless answer.

Comment: Just go through the fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind for left align is not data table.
It is because you loop through on object.
If you loop on object int key will be picked first.

```js
var data = {
  c: "c",
  b: "b",
  a: "a",
  1: "1"
};
for (var key in data) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

Comment: so what to do now? i want to align that on right side of table.

Comment: Do you want to align it at last position?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/draj8126/8th5dykj/68/  just look at this link i have so many columns as a key and i want them to start after Amount header and also those keys are dynamic it can appear on UI on the basis of user selection it can be 5 it can be 12 . In the above fiddle link i am only using 5 keys as a number

Comment: I have looked the code, I think you need to send an array of keys(column) from server. So by using it you can ensure sequence of column.

Comment: it cant be possible with java script because from server side with great difficulty if have done that :(

Comment: It's a behavior of javascript. You need  send array of keys from server.
Ex. ["OUTLET", "BILLDATE","TOTAL","AMOUNT","1","2"]
its the only way to ensure column sequence.